# How do I copy data from on table to another in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am currently making an application that lets you create students, and then mark them absent. I want to be able to do this by adding it into a separate table called AbsentStudents. But with the jparepository or the crudreposotroy don't give me these options.

I tried to create a new entity that was a replica of the students entity, then make the dao equal the findbyid of the student. it looked like this:

```
dao.equals(repo.findById(id));
```

Index.jsp:

```
<body>
<p> Add a student into the database:<p>
<form action ="addStudent">
    <input type = "text" name = "ID"><br>
    <input type = "text" name = "Name"><br>
    <input type = "text" name = "Teacher"><br>
    <input type = "submit">
</form>

<p> Mark a Student Absent<p>
<form action ="markAbsent">
    <input type = "text" name = "ID"><br>
    <input type = "submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Then the absentStudent, which is the same as student

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class AbsentStudent
{
    @Id
    private int id;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

I then created the dao of both the student and absent.

Finally, here is the controller. I left the autowired out.

```
@RequestMapping("/addStudent")
public String addStudent(Student student) {

    repo.save(student);
    return "index.jsp";

}

@RequestMapping("/markAbsent")
public ModelAndView markAbsent(@RequestParam int id) {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();

    dao.equals(repo.findById(id));

    mv.setViewName("absent.jsp");
    mv.addObject(dao);



    return mv;

}
```

}

I was expecting a page in the end, which would fetch all the absent students from the database, and post them on a single page. But, I get an error page.

> the data didn't copy from student to absent student.

Comment: Could I have some help?

Comment: Can you show where you declare `dao` and provide the code for that class?

Comment: public interface AbsentDao extends CrudRepository<AbsentStudent, Integer> {


}

Comment: I declare it at the top with @autowired.

Comment: @autowired AbsentDao dao. (In the controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to be able to do this by adding it into a separate table called AbsentStudents. But with the jparepository or the crudreposotroy don't give me these options.

Maybe @Query annotation inside dao (repository) interface will help with your problem ( https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query )

Comment: Thanks, but which query should I use to copy from student to AbsentStudent, and where should I put it?

Comment: In my opinion it will be better if you just add a new field into Student entity class (for example boolean absent, NUMBER(1,0) in database) and when you'll mark some student you will just update you students table using `@Modifying @Query(value = "update student set absent = 1 where id = :id", nativeQuery = true) public void markAbsentStudent(@Param("id") Integer studentId);`, and at the moment when you will need to get all absent students you will call another query `@Query(value = "select * from student where absent = 1", nativeQuery = true) public List<Student> getAbsentStudents();`

Comment: @Modifying annotation says that this query will modify some table in the database. The code i write above should be inside the interface that implements the jparepository or the crudrepository (repository for student)

Comment: nativeQuery attribute says that the code inside the value attribute is written in sql (it's jpql by default).

Comment: Nvm. Got it. Thanks!